# android -NullPointerException on open database in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I've a slidetab on my activity ,It has 4 fragments. Each fragment contains a listView and I fill this listview with a baseAdapter .

I've published my application and I got this error very much :

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3970)
at ir.radaar.goblin.Fragment_E$ListAdapter.<init>(Fragment_E.java:396)
at ir.radaar.goblin.Fragment_E$GetContacts.onPostExecute(Fragment_E.java:359)
at ir.radaar.goblin.Fragment_E$GetContacts.onPostExecute(Fragment_E.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my baseAdapter code :

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    DatabaseHandler db_e;

    public ListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = (Activity) activity;
        this.list = list;
        try {
                db_e = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
                if (!db_e.isOpen())
                    db_e.open();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            startActivity(new Intent (getActivity(), FistActiivty.class));
        }
        ostan = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ostan);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> geting(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_ekhtesasi, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (this.list.size() > 0)
            this.list.clear();
    }
}
```

Fragment_E.java line 396 is this :
db_e.open();

I don't know why does it keeps error. The same line on other fragments get error too .

on databaseHandler class, this is the class that opens the database :

```
public DatabaseHandler open() {
    helper = new OpenHelper(context);
    myDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Could you help me . Why does I get this error ?

thanks

Comment: Did you check if getActivity() returns null or not on this line: db_e = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity()); ?

Comment: @Xplouder , I didn't get this error my self but in the logs I have too many people that had this problem .is it possible that getActivity() be null ?

Comment: Assuming you are initializing the ListAdapter correctly i dont think so. Anyway why you are opening the database inside the adapter if you never using it? Also, looks like an error here     FistActiivty.class instead     FistActivity.class

Comment: replace getActivity() with activity.